# MEF Interface - Can I have optional voids?

Tags: c#, owin, mef

I have a C# Self Hosted Web API, that at some point needs to be extended with plugins.
I have created an Interface:

```
[InheritedExport]
public interface IMyPlugin
{
    void OnStart();
    void OnEnd();
}
```

In My plugin:

```
[Export(typeof(AnotherTYpe))]
[ExportMetadata("DisplayName", "My Plugin")]
[ExportMetadata("Description", "blabla")]
[ExportMetadata("Version", "1.0")]
public class ServiceTasks : IMyPlugin
{
    [Import("IMyPlugin", typeof(IMyPlugin))]
    public IHost Host { get; set; }

    public void OnStart()
    {

    }


    public void OnEnd()
    {

    }
    
}
```

But what I want is just to create in my plugin the "OnStart" void, I don't need in this plugin the OnEnd void, is it possible to write the plugin without this void?

If I delete it, it shows an error saying that It does not implement the interface member OnEnd.

Is it possible to make void optional in plugins?

Edit:

The interface is mine, and I can separate the members in the interface, so the user can just make the plugin for a member. But if I can make the defaults, I can join the members in the same interface. How can I make defaults and the default be empty?

Comment: If an interface contains a member, you **have** to add it to your type if you want the type to implement the interface. This is just regular C# and has nothing to do with MEF. You can leave it empty if you don't want it to do anything.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is no longer true in C# 8, which has default interface methods

Comment: Yes, if you are in control over the interfaces.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I have edited the question. The interface is mine, so I can just edit the interfaces, to create a default empty. With C# 8. Can anybody show an example? Thanks all

Comment: @erikkallen Has already done that, notice the `{ }` at the end of the method declarations in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could add empty default implementations of the methods.

```
public interface IMyPlugin
{
    public void OnStart() {}
    public void OnEnd() {}
}

public class MyPlugin : IMyPlugin
{
    public void OnStart() { Console.WriteLine("OnStart"); }
    // no OnEnd required
}
```